# Can I use "instance" and "case" like this?

Tags: word-usage

I want to write something about Android bus tracking system based on crowdsourcing, where the routes are determined by wifi:

> In order to exclude instances of passing buses, it only cases are considered, where the wifi is available  for longer than 90 seconds.

or

> In order to exclude cases of passing buses, it only circumstances are considered, where the wifi is available  for longer than 90 seconds.

Comment: Neither is correct.  "It only ___ are considered" is not correct syntax.  Would make more sense as "... buses, only cases where WiFi is available for longer than 90 seconds are considered."

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax would be

> it only considers (cases/circumstances) where ...

I assume *it* refers to the app you're describing. *cases* and *circumstances* seem equally acceptable in my opinion.